# Raspberry Pi Timed Shell script

Tags: linux, shell, raspberry-pi, node.js

I'd like a little help on how I would run a command over time. It's a node one. Basically I run a steam bot and I'd like it to restart over a certain amount of time. I'd like every 3 hours or just how I would do so.

Here's the command I'm trying to run overtime

```
cd /Home/Pi/Desktop/
node bot.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `cron`:

```
0 */3 * * * cd /Home/Pi/Desktop/ && /path/to/node bot.js
```

Comment: The idiomatic way to use `cd` in a script is to `(cd dir && command)`. Yours will probably still work though.

Comment: Best to only run `node` if the `cd` is successful, though.  Fixed.

Comment: No, you'd put it into your `cron` table.  Run `crontab -e`, add that line, save and exit your text editor.  Your tool will thenceforth be launched every three hours on the hour.

Comment: You can use a `cron` table to run any command, yes.

Comment: How would I close the previous termainal window so that way i dont have lots of windows open?

Comment: You could look into `nohup`, or add code to your javascript to check to see if it's already running and not start if that is the case.

Comment: Sorry I dont know how to code. Just the very very basics